TypeScript can't compile Mongoose query helper
I'm working on a TypeScript project that uses Mongoose and is compiled with tsc. When I try to use a query helper with .find():
import { InferRawDocType, Schema, model } from "mongoose";

export const mySchemaDefinition = {
  key: "string",
  value: "string"
} as const;
export type RawSchema = InferRawDocType<typeof mySchemaDefinition>;
export const mySchema = new Schema(mySchemaDefinition, {
  query: {
    byKey: function (key: string) {
      return this.where({ key: key });
    }
  }
});
export const MyModel = model("MyModel", mySchema);

MyModel.find({ key: "123" }).exec(); // OK
MyModel.findOne().byKey("123").exec(); // OK
MyModel.find().byKey("123").exec(); // Error

TypeScript throws an error during transpilation:
The 'this' context of type 'QueryWithHelpers<(Document<unknown, { byKey: <T extends Query<unknown, Document<unknown, {}, FlatRecord<{ readonly key: "string"; readonly value: "string"; }>> & FlatRecord<{ readonly key: "string"; readonly value: "string"; }> & { _id: ObjectId; } & { __v: number; }, {}, FlatRecord<{ readonly key: "string"; readonly value: "string"; }>, "find", Record<string, never>>>(this: T, key: string) => T; }, { readonly key: "string"; readonly value: "string"; }> & { readonly key: "string"; readonly value: "string"; 
} & { _id: ObjectId; } & { __v: number; })[], Document<unknown, { byKey: <T extends Query<unknown, Document<unknown, {}, FlatRecord<{ readonly key: "string"; readonly value: "string"; }>> & FlatRecord<{ readonly key: "string"; readonly value: "string"; }> & { _id: ObjectId; } & { __v: number; }, {}, FlatRecord<{ readonly key: "string"; readonly value: "string"; }>, "find", Record<string, never>>>(this: T, key: string) => T; }, { readonly key: "string"; readonly value: "string"; }> & { readonly key: "string"; readonly value: "string"; } & { _id: ObjectId; } & { __v: number; }, { byKey: <T extends Query<unknown, Document<unknown, {}, FlatRecord<{ readonly key: "string"; readonly value: "string"; }>> & FlatRecord<{ readonly key: "string"; readonly value: "string"; }> & { _id: ObjectId; } & { __v: number; }, {}, FlatRecord<{ readonly key: "string"; readonly value: "string"; }>, "find", Record<string, never>>>(this: T, key: string) => T; }, { readonly key: "string"; readonly value: "string"; }, "find", {}>' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'Query<unknown, Document<unknown, {}, FlatRecord<{ readonly key: "string"; readonly value: "string"; 
}>> & FlatRecord<{ readonly key: "string"; readonly value: "string"; }> & { _id: ObjectId; } & { __v: number; }, {}, FlatRecord<{ readonly key: "string"; readonly value: "string"; }>, "find", Record<string, never>>'.
  The types returned by 'lean(...).exec()' are incompatible between these types.
    Type 'Promise<({ readonly key: "string"; readonly value: "string"; } & { _id: ObjectId; } & { __v: number; })[]>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<{ readonly key: "string"; readonly value: "string"; } & { _id: ObjectId; } & { __v: number; }>'.
      Type '({ readonly key: "string"; readonly value: "string"; } & { _id: ObjectId; } & { __v: number; })[]' is not assignable to type '{ readonly key: "string"; readonly value: "string"; } & 
{ _id: ObjectId; } & { __v: number; }'.
        Type '({ readonly key: "string"; readonly value: "string"; } & { _id: ObjectId; } & { __v: number; })[]' is missing the following properties from type '{ readonly key: "string"; readonly value: "string"; }': key, value

But it only happens with .find, .findOne works fine.
The this context seems to be the right type.
Is this a problem with tsc configuration or is there a Mongoose type error I can fix?
Build command:
tsc index.ts --esModuleInterop --outDir ./build --noErrorTruncation

tsconfig.json (mostly targets the React app that is in the same project):
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}


The error occurs because the byKey query helper is not properly typed to handle both find() and findOne() operations. The current implementation assumes a single document return type, but find() returns an array. I hope it will fix.
export const mySchemaDefinition = {
  key: "string",
  value: "string"
} as const;
export const mySchema = new Schema(mySchemaDefinition, {
query: {
byKey: function<T extends Query<any, any>>(this: T, key: string) {
 return this.where({ key: key });
    }
  }
});

This change makes the byKey query helper generic enough to work with both find() and findOne() operations.
To avoid using any in Typescript code you can define a specific type for your schema and use it in the Query type. Here's how you can do it:
type MySchemaType = {
  key: string;
   value: string;
};

export const mySchemaDefinition = {
 key: "string",
value: "string"
} as const;
export const mySchema = new Schema(mySchemaDefinition, {
 query: {
 byKey: function<T extends Query<MySchemaType, typeof 
 mySchemaDefinition>>(this: T, key: string) {
 return this.where({ key: key });
  }
}
});


This does seem to work, as well as Query<any, RawSchema>, but is there a way to make it work without using any, or do I have to suppress the warning whenever I use a query?  Query<unknown, RawSchema> throws an error.

Yes to avoid using any in your TypeScript code, you can define a specific type for your schema and use it in the Query type.

I'm not familiar with mongoose types, so I'm not sure what type other than any would work with both find and findone

Thanks for the help, I've been trying to remove the anys, but so far the only other option I've come up with that works is this: byKey: function <ResultType, QueryOp, T extends Query<ResultType, RawSchema, object, RawSchema, QueryOp>>(this: T, key: string) {

It may not be the most convenient or optimal solution, but it illustrates the point.
import { InferRawDocType, Schema, model, Query } from "mongoose";

export const mySchemaDefinition = {
  key: "string",
  value: "string"
} as const;
export type RawSchema = InferRawDocType<typeof mySchemaDefinition>;

export const mySchema = new Schema<RawSchema>(mySchemaDefinition, {
  query: {
    byKey: function<T extends Query<any, RawSchema>>(this: T, key: string) {
      return this.where({ key: key });
    }
  }
});

export const MyModel = model("MyModel", mySchema);

MyModel.find({ key: "123" }).exec(); // OK
MyModel.findOne().byKey("123").exec(); // OK
MyModel.find().byKey("123").exec(); // OK

or if you want to avoid using Query<any, RawSchema>
import { Schema, model, Document, Model } from "mongoose";

interface MyDocument extends Document {
  key: string;
  value: string;
}

const mySchema = new Schema<MyDocument>({
  key: { type: String, required: true },
  value: { type: String, required: true }
});

mySchema.query.byKey = function (key: string) {
  return this.where({ key });
};

const MyModel: Model<MyDocument> = model("MyModel", mySchema);

MyModel.find({ key: "123" }).exec(); // OK
MyModel.findOne().byKey("123").exec(); // OK
MyModel.find().byKey("123").exec(); // OK

or even
import { InferRawDocType, Schema, model, Query } from "mongoose";

export const mySchemaDefinition = {
  key: "string",
  value: "string"
} as const;
export type RawSchema = InferRawDocType<typeof mySchemaDefinition>;

export const mySchema = new Schema<RawSchema>(mySchemaDefinition, {
  query: {
    byKey: function(this: Query<RawSchema[], RawSchema>, key: string) {
      return this.where({ key: key });
    }
  }
});

export const MyModel = model("MyModel", mySchema);

MyModel.find({ key: "123" }).exec(); // OK
MyModel.findOne().byKey("123").exec(); // OK
MyModel.find().byKey("123").exec(); // OK


Thanks for the answer, but the findOne line throws an error in all of the above cases
